# Tensorflow - Using batching to form a validation set

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm attempting to use tensorflow's batching system, as detailed here https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html to make predictions using a model that I trained previously. At the moment I have set the batch size that I use in tf.train.batch to be equal to the size of the data set that I want to make predictions over.

However, I want to create a validation set to test my predictions and avoid overfitting.

**Is there a way to separate a validation set from the training data using the batching system or is the only way to use placeholders?**

Below is a sample of my code responsible for training. It:

- Reads data from a CSV file, converts data to tensors
- Passes tensors to tf.train.shuffle_batch to train

  def input_pipeline(filename_list, batch_size, capacity):
      filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename_list,num_epochs=None)
      reader = tf.TextLineReader()
      key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

  ```
  # Defaults force key value and label to int, all others to float.
  record_defaults = [[1]]+[[46]]+[[1.0] for i in range(436)]
  # Reads in a single row from the CSV and outputs a list of scalars.
  csv_list = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
  # Packs the different columns into separate feature tensors.
  location = tf.pack(csv_list[2:4])
  bbox = tf.pack(csv_list[5:8])
  pix_feats = tf.pack(csv_list[9:])
  onehot = tf.one_hot(csv_list[1], depth=98)
  keep_prob = 0.5


  # Creates batches of images and labels.
  image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [pix_feats, onehot], 
      batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=4, capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=30000)

  return image_batch, label_batch
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your record_defaults.

So there's a couple of ways to do it.  you could have two different "shuffle_batch" one that will take in the training data and the other that will take in the validation data.  Then you call to run one or the other.

```
train_loss = train(train_set)
val_loss = val(val_set)

sess.run([train_loss]) # or sess.run([val_loss])
```

Placeholders are an alternative.

Comment: The problem is that my training data and my validation data are in the same file (it's a single large csv file). Is there a way, only using batching that I can get a randomly sampled validation set from the file? Sorry if this is trivial, as you can tell, I'm new to this.